# splitting string column into multiple columns based on key value item using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe where one column contains several information in a 'key=value' format.
There are almost a 30 different 'key=value' that can appear in that column will use 4 columns
for understanding ( _age, _city, _sal, _tag)

```
id  name   properties
0   A      {_age=10, _city=A, _sal=1000}
1   B      {_age=20, _city=B, _sal=3000, tag=XYZ}
2   C      {_city=BC, tag=ABC}
```

How can I convert this  string column into multiple columns?
Need to use spark scala dataframe for it.

The expected output is:

```
id  name   _age    _city    _sal    tag
0   A      10      A       1000       
1   B      20      B       3000   XYZ
2   C              BC             ABC
```

Comment: What is the type of your properties column? Struc or String?

Comment: String type is the datatype

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

```scala
df
  .select(
    col("id"), 
    col("name"), 
    col("properties.*"), 
    ..
  )
```

Comment: Datatype of the 'properties' column is string

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
val s = df.withColumn("dummy", explode(split(regexp_replace($"properties", "\\{|\\}", ""), ",")))
    val result= s.drop("properties").withColumn("col1",split($"dummy","=")(0)).withColumn("col1-value",split($"dummy","=")(1)).drop("dummy")
    result.groupBy("id","name").pivot("col1").agg(first($"col1-value")).orderBy($"id").show
```

Comment: Please suggest the answer for the above queries

Comment: Please share the valuable suggestion